# Applying conditions on a query using parse.com

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

My app is displaying the data from parse data base but i have to differentiate through query that in one listview it display the names of donars and in next list it displays the names of acceptors.

code for acceptors list

```
public class Donar_Acceptor_list extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
```

// ParseQueryAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.donar_acceptor_list);

    final ParseQueryAdapter adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter(this, "Data");
    adapter.setTextKey("username");


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
             new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
               public ParseQuery create() {
                 ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Data");
                 query.whereEqualTo("DonAcc", "donar");
                // query.orderByDescending("moneySpent");
                 return query;
               }
             };

         ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> Adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> (this, factory);

         adapter.setTextKey("username");


         // Attach it to your ListView, as in the example above
         ListView listVieww = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         listVieww.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

this is for donars list

```
public class donar_list extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
```

// ParseQueryAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.donar_list);

    final ParseQueryAdapter adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter(this, "Data");
    adapter.setTextKey("username");

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
             new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
               public ParseQuery create() {
                 ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Data");
                 query.whereEqualTo("DonAcc", "acceptor");
                // query.orderByDescending("moneySpent");
                 return query;
               }
             };

         ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> Adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);

         adapter.setTextKey("username");


         // Attach it to your ListView, as in the example above
         ListView listVieww = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         listVieww.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}